# Django Rest frame work "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect." error on JSONWebTokenAuthentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, postman

I want to send a POST request using POSTMAN and my url is like  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/restaurant/article/update/23`

On login I am sending a token which is Json web token (created like this) https://jpadilla.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#creating-a-new-token-manually

```
def get_token(user):
    jwt_payload_handler = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
    jwt_encode_handler = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER
    payload = jwt_payload_handler(user)
    return jwt_encode_handler(payload)
```

And on `login my api` response is like

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Successfully logged in",
    "data": {
        "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoyLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6IkRlbW9AZ21haWwuY29tIiwiZXhwIjoxNjAyNzU1MDE4LCJlbWFpbCI6IiJ9.sgLS4NofzDtdUSHYvuepRruw2PgTPLyGCdjIOiLdrkw",
        "restaurant": {
            "id": 1,
            "image": "/media/Restaurant/Entertainment.jpg",
            "restaurant": "Demo",
        }
    }
}
```

when I am using this token like this in post man its not working

[image: csrf token missing]

**BUT**   token provided in post man cookie when I use that it works like this .What's going on here ? any help would be highly appreciated.

[image: Image in post man cookie]

Comment: Try adding this `'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},` in your data.

Comment: in body in  form-data  option ? @KostasCharitidis

Comment: `"data": { 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'}, ...`

Comment: @KostasCharitidis  I am not using ajax , I am just checking on postman. Do this csrf token and JWT token are for diff purposes here ?

Comment: It's for authentication reasons to avoid forgery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formate to use token is

```
token : 'jwt token'
```

token is your token